# Is Ubunttu trying to be as annoying as Windows?

Tags: upgrade

I remember my first Ubuntu install - boot from a 3 1/2" floppy, tell it network install / dhcp / ftp, and come back in an hour and it was done.

I just upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10. It asked "Do you want to upgrade?" I replied "Yes" and went to bed, because I knew it had over 1,000 files and over 1 GB to download.

I got up this morning and checked the upgrade. It was stuck at a "Downloads complete. Do you want to upgrade?" prompt. I muttered, answered "Yes", and went to work.

Tonight I got home, again expecting the upgrade to be complete. Again it was hung at a prompt "Do you want to restart the services as they are upgraded?" When I answered Yes, the system chugged merrily along for a while longer.

I'm screaming at the computer now. It's been as frustrating as a Windows install. I answer "Yes, Yes Yes, Do it", get a reply like "This may take a while", leave and let it run (instead of being frustrated) only to come back and find that at some point before completion, the upgrade process has halted for yet another "Are you sure?" prompt.

And of course I know there will be a "you must reboot to complete the installation" phase soon.

I'm a big boy. When I say "yes I understand and I have backups" I mean "go ahead and do it, and I'll pick up the pieces if I have to."

It's very annoying to have "Are you sure?" followed (not immediately) by "Are you sure?" only to have another "Are you sure?" ad nauseum, and endless delays because it's waiting for the answer to a question that already has been answered.

Ubuntu is a great OS, but please stop trying to coddle us like Microsoft does, and treat us like grown-ups.

Comment: where is your question?

Comment: I (and presumably others) would consider an unattended release upgrade to be an advanced usage (mainly useful for servers).  Normal updates are easy to setup automatically in the various package management frontends.  For an unattended release upgrade you could try: `do-release-upgrade -f DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive`.  Be aware that I'd consider this dangerous and you absolutely should have backups before you do it.

Comment: This site is for questions , not for rants

Comment: Out of interest: which version of Ubuntu were you able to install from a floppy and then get the rest over network?  I don't remember that ever being an option for Ubuntu (Debian, yes, but even that hasn't been supported since etch IIRC -- whenever the boot-floppies package went away, I think etch or thereabouts was the last to use boot-floppies).

Answer (score 1):

Um, no? Ubuntu is giving you information about the upgrade. You only have 3 prompts to answer. I'm sure a "big boy" like you can handle 3 prompts.

- Do you want to upgrade
- Downloading complete, should we start installing
- Should we automatically restart services for you

That last prompt may actually be important for some users, since some services may have issues automatically restarting. For example, I answered yes to the prompts, but the BOINC service had problems during the update because my data folder wasn't mounted, so the automatic service restart had an error.